Highcharter package in R is not outputting plot in Rstudio but in R its ok
This is my code:
library(highcharter)

# install.packages("palmerpenguins")
data(penguins, package = "palmerpenguins") 

hchart(
  penguins,
  "scatter",
  hcaes(x = flipper_length_mm, y = bill_length_mm, group = species)
)

This is the output using R console:

But when I run it on Rstudio there is no plot:

This white screen on Viewer panel.

It takes a second but it loads for me https://i.imgur.com/eWV1rZf.png

What version of R are you using? There is a patched version of R 4.4.0 that resolves this issue, since it doesn't just affect highcharter, but other packages that rely on htmlwidgets such as plotly and leaflet.

Two things might be at play:

If your laptop/PC is old, it might have insufficient RAM or a graphics card that is too outdated for RStudio to properly render your plot. For example, I switched to an older graphics card on one of my computers a while back and since then I've been unable to render anything interactive on RStudio.
If RStudio hasn't previously given you this problem on your laptop/PC, then try clearing your workspace. Go to RStudio's menu and select Session -> Restart R and Clear Workspace. This will reset RStudio's environment and might resolve any temporary glitches.

